# Apple In-App Purchases: Generating New Products by Attaching Identifiers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am making an iPhone App which loads many objects from an external database and displays them to the user. The user has the option to purchase any one of these objects for $.99; when an object is purchased, more information about it is displayed to the user.
The database is large and gets several objects added to it daily. That's why it would be impractical to register each object as its own product on iTunes Connect. I think the best way to go about this would be to register only one type of product on iTunes Connect, and every time the user buys any object he will just be buying another copy of this product. Since the objects are all different, I'd need a way of identifying which is which. The objects all have unique codes in the database, but I have not seen anything in the documentation on how to attach them to products/purchases. Any ideas on how I'd do this?

EDIT: The objects I mention are simply collections of variables. It does not matter what they are exactly; I just want to know how to sell distinct objects using just one product associated with some sort of identifier.

Comment: What do you mean by objects, what is it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has to add each object independently in iTunes Connect. Inserting only one IAP into iTunes Connect and sell different objects is not accepted by Apple

Comment: But I know I can sell multiple copies of the same object. What if I just sold each copy as a token (all tokens would be the same) and then have the user exchange a token for an object he wants? That should be allowable, right? All the objects are of the same type, they're just sort of different instances of it (if that makes sense) so I think it should be fine by Apple

Comment: yes, but you can not sell the same object to the same person more than once, unless you specify that you are selling a consumable object, and I think this is not your case, if you did it your app will be rejected, almost for sure

Comment: It would be consumable; why would that be a problem? All I am selling is one-time information about an object (effectively just a string)

Comment: if you can justify that your IAP is a consumable then tere will be no problems, but if not you will has to create an IPA for each one

Comment: But in that case I am wondering one more thing. I know I can restore a complete list of part purchases the user made in the app at any time, but since I want to associate each of these consumables with a specific identifier, is there a way to store those too? Basically I am asking if I can store an array of strings so that it does not ever disappear if the user restarts the app

Comment: you can store a `NSArray` in the `NSUserDefaults`, this way this info will be added to the backups, but the only way to be 100% sure is storing it at your database server